# Assign ajax request result to variable in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I'm starting my jurney with AngularJS and have some question regarding assigning data from ajax request to simple JS variable.

I have services.js file, where after simple login we store username in a cookie.
I want to get from server an user ID based on his username. After that I want to receive this value in other factory in another file.

**services.js**

```
    angular.module('starter.services', ['ngResource', 'ngCookies', 'constants'])

  .factory('Auth', function ($cookieStore, $http, $q, MYTAMER) {
    var _user = $cookieStore.get('starter.user');
    var setUser = function (user) {
      _user = user;
      $cookieStore.put('starter.user', _user);
    };

    function getUserId(username) {
      return $http.get(MYTAMER.url + '/user/getId?username=' + username);
    }

    return {
      setUser: setUser,
      isLoggedIn: function () {
        return _user ? true : false;
      },
      getUser: function () {
        var userId = getUserId(_user.username)
          .then(function (response) {
            User.id = response.data;
          });
        return userId;
      },
      logout: function () {
        $cookieStore.remove('starter.user');
        _user = null;
      }
    }
  });
```

**dashboard-services.js**

```
angular.module('dashboard.services', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'constants'])

  .factory('Dashboard', function ($resource, $http, Auth) {
    var dashboardData = {};

    dashboardData.getGroups = function () {
      console.log(Auth.getUser());
    };

    return dashboardData;
  })
```

The problem is I get userId value inside http.get but returned value contains something like this:

```
Promise {$$state: Object}
$$state: Object
status: 1
value: 1
```

Could you please tell me how I can pass value stored in **response.data**? thank you

Comment: You're using the services you're making wrong. After including Auth, call it as a wrapper function: `Auth.getUser.then(function(user) { // your code here });`

Comment: Actually, even your `Auth` service is incorrectly written. I suggest looking for a guide on AngularJS services, such as the [Code Academy](http://www.codeacademy.com).

Comment: What's wrong with his Auth service? It's not the most glorious or readable use of private functions but it seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service, the userId you're returning in the `Auth.getUser` function is actually a [Javascript Promise Object](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).

In a nutshell, this means that when you call your `Auth.getUser` function, the browser (i.e. Javascript) has to asynchronously wait for the userId to be retrieved from your server (through the AJAX call you make) before your userId will be accessible in Javascript's memory. You use the `.then()` function in order to tell Javascript to wait for a response from the server.

So, your `getUser()` function should look more like:

```
getUser: function () {
  return getUserId(_user.username)
    .then(function (response) {
      User.id = response.data;

      return response.data; // This is what gets passed to the .then() function in Auth.getUser().then(function (userData) {})
    });
}
```

And then to get the userId you'd do the following:

```
Auth.getUser().then(function (userId) {
  // Javascript waits until Auth.getUser() is completed, then runs this callback function. This is the information that is returned from the line `return response.data`

  // Do what you need with the userId variable here
});
```